# Get rid of warning of viewpagerandroid and slider for RN 0.59

Tags: react-native

After upgrading to RN 0.59, there are 2 warning messages showing on android emulator screen every time during the test:

```
Warning: ViewPagerAndroid has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-community/viewpager' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-viewpager

Warning: Slider has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-community/slider' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-slider
```

There are several online posts talking about those warnings but there is no solution to get rid of it. When I see those 2 warnings, does it mean that my app code is using the obsolete package? I am doing a real time chat app and would like to know how to get rid of those warnings on `android` emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that in futeure if you update RN for your project ViewPager might be removed and your code wont work, for now it will work fine

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of the warning? It caused the other component malfunctioning. Also how to check if my code is using viewpager and slider?

Comment: you can search for it in node_modules but it will take lot of time